# How to transfer data of one collection into another of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, typescript, postman, nestjs

Am working on nestjs.I have two collections one in orders and second is payment and i want to retrieve one single entry from orders collections and save that same entry into payment collection.

Here is the code of services:

```
async order(name){
    const list=this.usersmodel.find({name:name}).exec()
    //return list
    try{
        if(list){
            const x=this.usersmodel.aggregate([
                {$out:"payment"}
            ])
            return "data saved in payment collection"
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        return(error.message)
    }
}
```

Here is the code of controller:

```
@Get('orderdata')
async orderdata(@Body('name')name){
    return this.usersService.order(name)
}
```

By using these code lines neither i got desired output nor i got any error. I got "data saved in payment collection" when am hitting API in postman but i didn't get the entries in my payment collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here, in this line

```
const list = this.usersmodel.find({ name: name }).exec()
```

this is an `asynchronous` block of code, so the next lines will be executed without waiting for this list to be resolved

you have to use `await` keyword to enforce javascript to wait until this line is executed before executing the next lines

```
const list = await this.usersmodel.find({ name: name }).exec()
```

also, the aggregate pipeline is taking the whole order documents to the payment collection, as there is no filtering applied to that orders in the aggregate pipeline

so you have to add $match stage to your aggregate pipeline, in order to add the list of orders that have the name you specified

also note that we need `await` in the aggregate too as this is an asynchronous block of code, so wait until this aggregation to be done then execute the return statement

so the whole function should look something like

```
async order(name) {
    const list = await this.usersmodel.find({ name: name }).exec()
    //return list
    try {
        if(list){
            await this.usersmodel.aggregate([ // note the await here
                { $match: { name: name } }, // filtering the orders
                { $out: "payment" } // move them to the payment collection
            ])

            return "data saved in payment collection"
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        return(error.message)
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: i followed your approach but still that's not working

Comment: Is there any issue or error happened? could you share more info, or if it's possible, could you share the github repository, if that's possible?

Comment: your approach is good the fault was mine and i recognized my fault now. But one another issue arises can you provide solution for this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700144/how-to-transfer-multiple-data-from-one-collection-to-another-using-out-aggregat

Comment: Okay cool, could you accept this as the answer to your question so anyone searching for some help can find it helpful?

Comment: Yeah sure and pls consider my other query and provide the solution if possible.

Comment: @sahil, check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720132/12371475, hope it helps