# How to transfer multiple data from one collection to another using $out aggregation

Tags: typescript, postman, aggregate, lookup, nestjs

I am working on nestjs and I have two collections one is order and the second is payment. Now I need to retrieve one document from the collection order and save it into payment collection which is working properly but the issue is when I am trying to save the second document into payment collection then my first document is overwritten. In other words, the first document has vanished after submitting the second document. I want to save every document in payment collection which i retrieved from orders document.

Here is the code of service:

```
async order(name){
    const list=await this.usersmodel.find({name:name}).exec()
    //return list
    try{
        if(list){
            const x=await this.usersmodel.aggregate([
                { $match: { name: name } },
                {$out:"payment"}
            ])
            return "data saved in payment collection"
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        return(error.message)
    }
}
```

code of controller-:

```
@Post('orderdata')
async orderdata(@Body('name')name){
    return this.usersService.order(name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the docs, `$out` is replacing the whole collection if it exists, with the one you provided, so when you do it, it will replace the old one

if your `mongodb` version is > 4.2, you can use `$merge` instead,

in `$merge`, it adds the new document to the collection if it exists, also you can define the behavior if the new document already exists (keep the old one, or overwrite it) and if it does not exist (insert or ignore it)

you can see all of that in the documentation of [$merge here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge)

also you can find a comparison between [$out and $merge here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#comparison-with-merge)

in your code, it should be something like

```
async order(name) {
    const list = await this.usersmodel.find({ name: name }).exec()
    //return list
    try {
        if(list) {
            const x = await this.usersmodel.aggregate([
                { $match: { name: name } },
                { $merge: { into: "payment" } } // you can define other options here like if the document already exists, keep the old one or not and so on, all of that you can find in the documentation
            ])
            return "data saved in payment collection"
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        return(error.message)
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Everything is working fine now and i got one more issue on this that I want to store multiple documents like suppose i have already saved doc_1,doc_2,doc_3,doc_4 in collection_2 from collection_1 and the situation arises that again i need to save same doc_1 in collection_2 which is fetched from collection_1. I don't get duplicate entries of the same document in my collection. How do achieve this. Can you please provide any solution on this ?

Comment: If you need to overwrite the existing doc_1, then use `{ $merge: { into: "payment", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace" } }` .... if you need to keep the current one then use `{ $merge: { into: "payment", on: "_id", whenMatched: "keepExisting" } }` ... if you need to merge the new one with the existing one use `{ $merge: { into: "payment", on: "_id", whenMatched: "merge" } }` ... read the docs for more info https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge

Comment: no i don't want to merge a new one into existing one. I need to add same document again and again if that document already exists. Suppose I have doc_1 already saved in collection_2 and then I save doc_2 in collection_2, now again I need to add one more document doc_1 in collection_2. I used the 3rd query of your previous comment but still output remains the same.

Comment: for more clarity, you can check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768900/how-to-add-multiple-same-type-of-documents-in-mongodb